# Changing Font in Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, wordpress-theming

I'm currently using the Wordpress 'Square' Theme : https://hashthemes.com/wordpress-theme/square/

I looking to modify the font in the navigation menu, drop down menus, and in posts/pages.

I have true type files of my desired fonts, but I'm not sure how I should modify the CSS to achieve what I want.

any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Mo

Comment: Have you tried their documentation? - https://hashthemes.com/documentation/square-documentation/

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig I have looked through the documentation and submitted this same question on their support forums.. but no luck. Turns out I may have to purchase a child theme from the developers in order to fully customize the theme,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add font family in style.css or custom css file i used this true type script in my theme like this

```
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/uhs1xwe.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
```

And in css file i used font like this way

```
.header_menu ul li {
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 18px 0 0;
    font-family: "sofia-pro";
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use the 'script src' tag?

I've uploaded my desired font's ttf to the designated fonts folder in my wordpress server. Thought it would already be installed/uploaded, ready to use.

Comment: this is how i add the true type fonts or if you have add ttf fonts in fonts folder then you can add in css please paste here what you have

Answer (score 0):

In style.css, write this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: FontName;  
src: url(public_html/your-site/wp-content/themes/your-theme/fonts/FontName-Regular.ttf);  
font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Then  use

```
body{font-family: FontName !important;}
```

see here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-wordpress/
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/custom-fonts-css/?utm_expid=3606929-109.P6e7JvhjTrWFxwrJZjRkog.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F

Comment: Please tell me what happen after using this.